# SourceTree, how to pause on Pull?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using sourcetree and one thing I don't like is that when you do a pull it automatically closes(I think if there is a problem it does not close the dialog).

I don't like this as I would like to see what files where downloaded and if any are merged. Is there away to stop this auto close?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only way to do this is to check the `Show full output` checkbox before the pull completes. Then, the dialogue will stay open until you un-check the checkbox.

Comment: that is hard to check fast enough sometimes.

Comment: then I'm not sure there's another way to do it. You could always fetch, though, and that will just get the commits, but not actually merge them into the local branches

Comment: Not sure, but there must be a config file that will allow you to have that checkbox checked as the default configuration.

Answer (score 0):

During any operation, SourceTree has the option to display full console output (presented as a checkbox under the progress bar).  If this is enabled, the output window will remain open until you manually close it.

SourceTree has the option to automatically use this behavior for all operations.  In the Options menu, on the "General" tab, check the option to "Always display full console output."  This will prevent all progress dialogs from closing automatically.